# Get value of an array when changing price via woocommerce_before_calculate_totals

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

So i have an array of products with there respectable sale price.

Normally getting value from an array is simple as below:

```php
$the_sups = array(
    21179 => 14.99,     //shine
    21169  => 17.95,    //boost
    1665  => 19.15,     //flexx
    1663  => 17.85,     //revive
    1661 => 19.75,      //muscle
    1657  => 17.85      //maximus
);
echo $the_sups[21179];
```

Which will return `14.99`

And for the life of me i keep get a getting return of `NULL` when passing though the `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals`

Below is code im using which i know should work if the price is returned from the array:

```php
$sup_discount= 0.9;

$the_sups = array(
    21179 => 14.99,     //shine
    21169  => 17.95,    //boost
    1665  => 19.15,     //flexx
    1663  => 17.85,     //revive
    1661 => 19.75,      //muscle
    1657  => 17.85      //maximus           
);

foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $hash => $value ) {

    if( in_array( 52, $value['data']->get_category_ids() ) ) {

         echo $value['product_id'];  //IS 21179

         $product_value = $the_sups[$value['product_id']];
         var_dump($product_value); //IS ALWAYS NULL

         $value['data']->set_price($product_value * $sup_discount);

    }         
}
```

Could someone explain what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do it, tested with WooCommerce 4.1.0

```php
function action_woocommerce_before_calculate_totals( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 ) return;

    /* SETTINGS */

    $sup_discount = 0.9;

    $the_sups = array(
        21179  => 14.99, // shine
        21169  => 17.95, // boost
        1665   => 19.15, // flexx
        1663   => 17.85, // revive
        1661   => 19.75, // muscle
        1657   => 17.85, // maximus
    );

    /* END SETTINGS */

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $value ) {    
        // Get product id
        $product_id = $value['product_id'];

        if( in_array( 52, $value['data']->get_category_ids() ) ) {
            echo $product_id;

            $product_value = $the_sups[ $product_id ];

            var_dump($product_value);

            $value['data']->set_price( $product_value * $sup_discount );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'action_woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: thank you for this how do i go about  making sure this does not change on chekcout since the prices revert back to normal

Comment: The price is not adjusted as you proceed. Unless the problem is about minicart. Since WC 3.6, using woocommerce_before_calculate_totals hook for cart item changes is not reflected in minicart. 
If this is not the case, the problem lies elsewhere

Comment: hi yes im not using minicart hmmmmm im gonna have to dig around

Comment: any suggestions ?

Comment: Most likely a conflict with a other plugin(s) or previous custom code. 
Theme related seems unlikely but not entirely excluded.

Comment: hi thanks it was my fault i had the "woocommerce_before_calculate_totals" being called inside another function "woocommerce_check_cart_items" so called it on its own with user_roles checks and works perfectly thank you for your help